# Open local website on computer from phone on same network

Tags: mobile, nginx, localhost

I have a local sandbox website on my computer running on nginx. I have chrome canary and that's what I"ve been using to test the various media sizes. Of course, this doesn't stack up against actual hands-on testing to get an idea of the feel of the website.

So, is there a way to be able to access a website running on my computer from the same network? Even if I have to use a specific app. I would like to use the same URL. `dev.mywebsite.com` and `mywebsite.com` run a on a server, `sandbox.mywebsite.com` is on my machine (this is the one I would like to access). I don't need to access to it remotely, just when I'm on my network is fine.

**Note:** I need to use the actual URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If sandbox.mywebsite.com maps to localhost on your computer, then by mapping sandbox.mywebsite.com in the hosts file of your phone to the local network IP address of your computer e.g. 192.168.1.9, you should be able to access it on the phone.

I have done this using android with hosts editor, connecting to apache running on an ubuntu laptop.

There are also many google results for this, so you may be able to find something there for your specific configuration.